# Hosting a multiple domains in pyramid

Tags: python, mongodb, virtualhost, scalability, pyramid

I am trying to design a SaaS app using pyramid. Clients will be able to design their facet of the app and their facet should be able to be served via the app.

To make things simpler to understand, let's say for example that we want to create an e-commerce SaaS app. The users should be able to create their own e-commerce site within the app and then access it with their own fqdn from the app if they wish.

I understand that we will need to address at least two issues and probably a third one:

1. Which fqdn the specific request is about.
2. How to distinguish static assets for each different fqdn.
3. How to connect to a different database for each fqdn.

Issue **(1)** can be easily addressed using `request.domain` (or `request.host`, `request.host_url`, etc.) as far as views and routes are concerned (I think). I am not sure, though, how I can address **(2)** and **(3)**. The reason I am mentioning **(3)** is because I think that it's better to scale horizontally (having separate databases for each different fqdn) than vertically (having one database with huge tables/collections/whatevers containing data for all fqdns).

Moreover, let's keep in mind that our app should be able to live on a multiple-application-servers setup, which means that if configuration functions are needed to be called on one application server to e.g. update views dynamically, then the rest of the application servers hosting the same app should be able to be somehow informed about this configuration change as well.

Any ideas on how to resolve these issues (with an example, please) or any suggestions on how the architecture of this app could change to be more scalable and easy to develop are more than appreciated!

Thanks all in advance!

**EDIT:**
OK, I thought of a "hack" that generates different views for each different fqdn without using any static views in my configuration. I won't post the hack as a self reply yet, because it doesn't seem very elegant to me; but if I come with no better solutions and nobody proposes a better solution I'll post it :).

The general idea is to create a view (**not** a static view) that will serve our static paths with a `*stararg` (eg `config.add_route('my_static_view', '/static/*subpaths')` that will handle the static assets along with its route (eg. `config.add_route('my_static_view', '/static')`).

We will also need a `static_view` object within the same scope (let's call it `static_view_obj`) that will be used to serve our static content (we don't need to reinvent the wheel, we'll use pyramid's `satic_view`'s functionality to serve our static assets). Within our `my_static_view` function we can alter `static_view_obj`'s content to serve a different static path for each different `request.domain`.

Comment: The topic is so huge I'm even afraid to start :) Do you think the question would me more answerable if it was split into 3 or 4 smaller concrete questions?

Comment: @Sergey, first of all thanks for you comment! I know it's a huge subject, and I understand your concerns, but I am afraid that if we split the question into smaller pieces, we'll lose the purpose of the question. It's a design question and I think it should be seen as a whole. Nonetheless, if more people think it should be split, then I could split it. But at least, we could leave the question as is to seek for answers related to the design of such an app: i.e. are the answers to the 3 questions mentioned indeed all that's needed or do we need more sub-questions to be answered?

Comment: Hmmm...and another suggestion: would it make sense to move the question (if possible) to the documentation section? Although I assume that the documentation section does not contain questions with answers...